# How to correctly specify max distance in geoNear query in Mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am querying a MongoDB collection from an app built with Express + Mongoose. I am looking for documents within a certain distance of geographical point.  The results show documents well outside the max distance that I am specifying.

This the model for the collection I'm querying:

```
LocationSchema = new mongoose.Schema({  
    id: {
        type: String,
        unique: true
    },
    ref: String,
    name: String,
    loc: {
        type: [Number],  // [<longitude>, <latitude>]
        index: '2d'      // create the geospatial index
    }
});
```

This is the code that queries the DB (via Mongoose):

```
var queryOptions = {
    maxDistance: 30,
    // maxDistance : 30 / 6371, // <-- (this doesn't work)
    distanceMultiplier: 6371, // tell mongo how many radians go into one kilometer.
    spherical: true,
    limit: 60
};

location.geoNear([latitude, longitude], queryOptions, processResults);
```

In this screenshot, the coords I specified in the query are the center of Dublin.  The results, as you can see, are much further away than the 30km max distance I specified.

Where have I gone wrong?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in this line of code:

```
location.geoNear([latitude, longitude], queryOptions, processResults);
```

It should be longitude first, then latitude!  Changing it to this resolved the issue:

```
location.geoNear([longitude, latitude], queryOptions, processResults);
```

Simple.